# What the correct translation of "to be about to lose something"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request, expression

I was wondering what the right translation of the phrase "to be about to lose something" is?

> I truly need help as I am about to lose everything, but I don't know what to do.
>   (Ich brauche wirklich Hilfe, da ich alles verlieren werde, aber ich weiß nicht, was ich tun soll.)

Comment: Re. your title - Careful: about [to lose *it*](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/to+lose+it.html), which has a totally different meaning, it's colloquial for "become very mad" or "going postal". To lose *sth* (house, money, job...) is the meaning you intend to translate.

Comment: Could you clarify why this is no proofreading question, please?

Comment: soryy for my fingertips Stephie, I'll edit my post

Comment: Any dictionary gives you a proper translation for "to be about to do something" as well as for "to lose something". So, what's unclear after consulting the dictionaries?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, due to the example you have given, you might think of the phrase "to be about to *lose* (sth.)"; one "o" more or less makes a difference. "To be about to lose" can be tranlsted to "dabei/ kurz davor sein (etwas) zu verlieren".

Secondly, "To be about to *loose* (sth.)", on the other hand, means "Dabei sein (etwas) zu lockern", but that's probably not what you wanted to ask for.

Comment: I like the "kurz davor sein..." translation for *being about to*.

Comment: If you don't need a literal translation you could also say: *...ich fürchte alles zu verlieren...*

Answer (score 2):

Please note that *I'm about to lose it* translates to

> Ich bin kurz davor, auszuflippen/auszurasten/durchzudrehen!

It is an idiomatic expression.

Now, let us look at your sentence:

*to be about to do something* translates to *kurz davor sein, etwas zu tun*. *to lose something* translates to *etwas verlieren*. *to lose everything* translates to *alles verlieren*, so when we combine this

*I'm about to lose everything* translates to

> Ich bin kurz davor, alles zu verlieren.

Answer (score 2):

I am also using "to be about to lose something" structure often and I prefer using *Im Begriff sein, etwas zu tun*

In your example, it could be translated as

> Ich bin im Begriff, alles zu verlieren

The Duden dictionary gives also following examples under "Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter" if you search for the "Begriff"

> im Begriff[e] sein/stehen (gerade anfangen wollen, etwas zu tun: sie
>   sind im Begriff zu gehen; ich stand im Begriff, das Haus zu>
>   verlassen)